# Getting sub-counts along with Average and Count

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, average

I have two tables...

```
MODULES                ENROLMENTS
GroupNo                StudentNo
Title                  GroupNo
Tutor                  CourseworkMark
DayNo                  ExamMark
Time
Room
Semester
```

I wish to create a view that displays the average mark achieved in coursework and exam for each module and also a count of the number of students who achieved >70, 60-69, 50-59, 40-49 and <40. Is this possible?

I have the average marks worked out with...

```
SELECT Title,
       AVG(CourseworkMark) AS AverageCoursework,
       AVG(ExamMark) AS AverageExam
FROM tblModules INNER JOIN tblEnrolments
   ON tblModules.GroupNo = tblEnrolments.GroupNo
GROUP BY Title;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a SUMmed CASE expression to do this;

```
SELECT Title,
       AVG(CourseworkMark) AS AverageCoursework,
       AVG(ExamMark) AS AverageExam,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CourseworkMark > 70 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CourseworkMarkOver70,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CourseworkMark BETWEEN 60 AND 70 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CourseworkMarkOver60To69,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CourseworkMark BETWEEN 50 and 59 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CourseworkMarkOver50To59,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CourseworkMark BETWEEN 40 and 49 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CourseworkMarkOver40To49,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CourseworkMark < 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CourseworkMarkUnder40
FROM tblModules INNER JOIN tblEnrolments
   ON tblModules.GroupNo = tblEnrolments.GroupNo
GROUP BY Title;
```